# How would I show that these parametrizations are equivalent?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

If we consider a half-sphere in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

We can parametrize it in two ways

$$f_1(a',b') = (a',b',\sqrt{1-a'^2-b'^2}) ,\space (a',b') \in \{ (a',b')\in \mathbb{R^2}:a'^2+b'^2 < 1 \} := K$$
and

$$f_2(a,b) = (\cos a \cos b,\sin a \cos b,\sin b),\space (a,b) \in \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2}:a \in (0,2\pi), b \in (0,\pi)\}:=G$$

These mappings have the same range. If I could map one domain to the other then this would prove that they are equivalent.

If I define $\phi : G \rightarrow K$ by
$\phi(a,b) = (\frac{b}{\pi}\cos(a),\frac{b}{\pi}\sin(a))$
this maps the square to the circle and $\phi^{-1}(a',b') = (\arctan\frac{b'}{a'},\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}\pi)$ maps the circle to the square.

If I compose phi and its inverse I get the identity map. BUT

$$f_2 \circ \phi^{-1} = \langle \frac{u}{\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}}\cos(\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}\pi), \frac{v}{\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}}
\cos(\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}\pi) , \sin(\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}\pi) \rangle$$

This is not equal to $f_1$. Where have I made an error?

> After an extended discussion with mathbeing:

If we redefine $K $ as $\tilde{K}:=K \backslash \{ (x,0): x \in [0,1) \}$

We find $\phi = f_2^{-1} \circ f_1 = \big(\arctan(\frac{b'}{a'}) ,\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{1-a'^2-b'^2}}{\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}}) \big)$

and $\phi^{-1} = (\cos a \cos b, \sin a \cos b)$

both of these functions are differentiable.

Hence the parametrisations are the same up to a change in variables.

Comment: Their are not the same; their range is the same. Consider the more simple example; $f_n(t)=(t^n,t^n)$ for $t\in[0,1]$. If $n\neq k$ then $f_n\neq f_k$ but the range of every $f_n$ is the same.

Comment: I see your point! thanks for pointing that out, there must be a way of showing that these parametrizations are equivalent though..

Comment: It depends on what you consider equivalent. A typical approach in differential geometry would be to try to show that the change of parametrization is a diffeomorphism. Or you could try to prove that they preserve some property.

Comment: Would $\phi$ be considered as a diffeomorphism? It is a bijection and its inverse is differentiable.

Comment: The range of $\phi$ is not $K$. It misses the segment $\{(x,0):0\leq x<1\}$.

Comment: oh!. Would you be able to give a hint towards finding a suitable diffeomorphism?  I have been scratching my head at this all day.

Comment: If you redefine the domain of $f_1$ in order to achieve $Im(f_1)=Im(f_2)$ then $\phi:=f_2^{-1}\circ f_1$ is a bijection. Find its expresion in terms of $a'$ and $b'$ and study if it and its inverse are differentiable. If so, then you can say that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are equivalent up to a differentiable change of variables. Notice that this would mean that $f_1=f_2\circ \phi$.

Comment: Is what I have put in the edit, in the ball park?

Comment: $\phi$ is defined in $S$ so it doesn't make sense to say that it is differentiable over $\tilde{K}$. As for the rest, if you've done the calculations right, then it is fine. I would still add that what you're doing is showing that the two parametrizations are the same up to a differentiable change of variables.